# Change an id for a class

Tags: jquery

I have a div centered vertically and horizontally in the page. But when this div id is larger than the screen cannot be centered and is cut. So I tried to detect if the div is larger than the document change to margin 0 auto. But I don't know how to do that. Is it possible to remove the id properties and give it the class "onTop" properties?

I have it here to play: http://jsfiddle.net/c9unU/

jQuery:

```
$(function(){      
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var contenttHeight = $("#content").height();

    if(documentHeight < contenttHeight ){
        /* give it the class onTop */
    }else{
        /* give it the id content */
    }   
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="content"> some text inside</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {margin: 0;padding: 0;color:#fff; font-size:40px;}

#background {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border: 0px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.onTop {
    position: relative;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:green;
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
    border:0px;
  }

#content {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-300px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    background-color: red;
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
    border:0px;
}
```

Comment: why not simply use `max-width:300px` ?

Comment: Have you try use `margin: 0 auto` instead of this hack?

Comment: The id has to be centered horizontally and vertically if the page is bigger than the id. Margin 0 auto if the id is smaller than the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are approaching situation as if you only have a choice of using ID CSS **OR** class CSS rules. It's very simple to combine both:

```css
#content {
   /* properties here*/
}

/* CSS for #content when class onTop is added to it*/
#content.onTop {
    position: relative;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:green;
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
    border:0px;
  }
```

JS

```
$(function(){      
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var contenttHeight = $("#content").height();
     $('#content').toggleClass('onTop', documentHeight < contenttHeight)

})
```

Second argument of `toggleClass()` is a boolean to indicate add or remove class

Comment: This is a very good solution, thank you. But my problem comes when the user resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){      
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var contenttHeight = $("#content").height();

    if(documentHeight < contenttHeight ){
        $('#content').removeAttr('id').addClass('onTop');
    }else{
        $('.onTop').removeClass().attr('id', 'content');
    }   
})
```

Comment: If the document height changes again without reloading the page is it possible to change again? (my problem is with tablets when change to landscape to portrait)

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Give Id by default, and add and remove classes. Make sure the class css is **after** the default css. Keep ot simple.

CSS:

```
#content.onTop {
    position: relative;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:green;
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
    border:0px;
  }
```

JQuery:

```
if(documentHeight < contenttHeight ){
        /* give it the class onTop */$('#content').addClass('onTop');
    }else{
        /* remove class ontop */
    }
```

You don't actually need to remove class, as it wont be there in first place. But it's better if you adjust screen on window resize.

Comment: This is very good!. But I don't know the hight of the content and I don't know if the first time the document will be larger than the content or not. For instance in small tablets. I need it to change every time that the window changes. Is it possible?

Comment: yes there are javascript handlers for window.onresize..and document and window size..google it.